# How do I cover a React component with a background img completely?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want the image to cover the entire width and height of the page

**Note:** I'm not using Bootstrap.

[image]

This is The Landing page component

```
 import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
const Landing = () => {
    return (

      <Fragment>
        <div className=''>
          <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div className="jumbo container">
              <div className="row justify-content-center text-center">
                <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-6">
                  <h1 className="display-5">The Coolest Online storage of personal Information</h1>

                  <p className="lead">How you store contacts have never been more secure. Where you choose to work has impact on your productivity and creativity.</p>

                  <Fragment>
                    <ul>
                  <li><Link className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" to="/register">Get Started</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                  </Fragment>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
}
export default Landing
```

This is my App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <ContactState>
        <AlertState>
    
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
          
            <div className="container">
              <Alerts />
              <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/landing' component={Landing} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />

                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              </Switch>
            
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>

        </AlertState>
      </ContactState>
    </AuthState>
  )
}
export default App
```

This is the styling for the landing page.

```
.jumbo {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('./img/hero.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 89vh;
}
```

I would like for the image to cover the entirety of the page as it is a landing page.
What am I doing wrong?

there's a container class i think hinders it from working. but if I remove it, it affects the whole application

```
  .container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the `<div>` parent element (where you want to add the background)
add `style={}` property, in the `style={}` do this:

```
{background: `url()`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add your background image to jumbotron's **parent** div because your jumbotron seems to have some margin from the top, right, and left sides.

```
.jumbotron-parent {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('./img/hero.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 89vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it still doesnt work. though theres a container class in the body of my application that I think hinders it from working

Comment: yeah if your parent container has padding from the body then it prevents it from being stuck to corners.